# Importing Spring bean definition file using relative path

Tags: java, spring

I am writing spring configurations for my project in JAVA. I am new to spring and not to able to figure out the errors related to spring.
I have the following file structure:

```
ProjectName
--> src
    --> META-INF
        --> jobs
            -->edx
               -->request-details.xml
            -->clients.xml
            -->daos.xml
            -->environment.xml
        --> request-details-edx-upload.xml
```

In META-INF/request-details-edx-upload.xml I import the following:

```
<import resource="jobs/environment.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/jobs/edx/request-details.xml" />
<import resource="jobs/clients.xml" />
<import resource="jobs/daos.xml" />
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/jobs/edx/request-details.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/request-details-edx-upload.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:  Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for attribute [dataSetName]
Offending resource: class path resource [META-INF/jobs/edx/request-details.xml]
```

request-details.xml is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    ">
 <!-- RequestDetails EDX data upload dao -->
 <bean id="requestDetailsDataUploadDao" class="com.amazon.edx.dao.DataUploadDaoEdxClientImpl"
 context:providerName="scot"
 context:subjectName="${edxRequestDetailsSubject}"
 context:dataSetName="by-01-day"
 context:keyName="${regionValue}"
 context:edxClient-ref="edxClient"
 />
 <util:list id="requestDetailsColumnMetaData" value-type="com.amazon.edx.transformer.ColumnMetaData">
        <ref bean="Column"/>
        <ref bean="Column1"/>                   
 </util:list>
<bean id="Column" class="com.amazon.edx.transformer.ColumnMetaData"
    context:attributeName="Id"
    context:dataType="VARCHAR2"
    context:columnDisplayName="IMS"
/>    
<bean id="Column1" class="com.amazon.edx.transformer.ColumnMetaData"
    context:attributeName="id1"
    context:dataType="VARCHAR2"
    context:columnDisplayName="IMS"
/>
<util:constant id="tabDelimiter"
        static-field="com.amazon.edx.transformer.Delimiters.TAB_DELIMITER"    />


 <!-- RequestDetails data backup --> 
<bean id="requestDetailsDataTransformer" class="com.amazon.edx.transformer.DataTransformerImpl"
context:dataFlattener-ref="requestDetailsDataFlattener"
context:columnMetadata-ref="requestDetailsColumnMetaData"
context:delimiter="{tabDelimiter}"
/>
 </beans>
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong with my import of the relative path?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide text of `request-details.xml`?

Comment: added the request-details.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is wrong schema definition. Try to remove namspace `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"` from `<beans>` tag. Instead add `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"` namespace. Also you should replace all `context:` suffix with `p:` suffix. Proper xml using shortcut with the p-namespace should looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

   <!-- RequestDetails EDX data upload dao -->
   <bean id="requestDetailsDataUploadDao" class="com.amazon.edx.dao.DataUploadDaoEdxClientImpl"
      p:providerName="scot"
      p:subjectName="${edxRequestDetailsSubject}"
      p:dataSetName="by-01-day"
      p:keyName="${regionValue}"
      p:edxClient-ref="edxClient"
   />

   ....

</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Using p-namespace resolved this error. But I was getting further errors, used c-namespace instead. Worked well. Thanks.